# How to implement in C++ a container for writing object data when it changes?

Tags: c++

The question is, are there ready-made implementations of the container that would allow you to write the data of an object when it changes or inform about it? The container must support simple and complex types, including numbers, strings, vectors, and maps.

I wrote a rough implementation of what is required, but I'm not sure if there are no bugs, do you know how it could be done better?

I was unable to implement index access to maps, can you please tell me how to do this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>

class TestStorage {
    public:
    void write() {
        std::cout << "write data to Storage" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<class S, class C>
class StatVar {
    public:
    template<class... Args>
    explicit StatVar(std::shared_ptr<S> const& storage, Args&&... args) : m_var{std::forward<Args>(args)...}, m_storage{storage} {}
    
    template<class U, class... Args>
    explicit StatVar(std::shared_ptr<S> const& storage, std::initializer_list<U> ilist, Args&&... args) : m_var{ilist, std::forward<Args>(args)...}, m_storage{storage} {}
    
    class Modificator {
        public:
        Modificator(StatVar<S, C>& stat_var): m_stat_var{stat_var}, m_var{m_stat_var.m_var} {
            std::cout << "begin modify" << std::endl;
        }
        
        ~Modificator() {
            std::cout << "end modify" << std::endl;
            if (m_stat_var.m_var != m_var) {
                std::cout << "object is modified" << std::endl;
                m_stat_var.m_var = m_var;
                m_stat_var.m_storage->write();
            }
        }
        
        template <typename K>
        auto& operator[](const K& key) {
            std::cout << "index access" << std::endl;
            return m_var[key];
        }
        
        operator C&() {
            std::cout << "reference access" << std::endl;
            return m_var;
        }
        
        C& operator *() {
            std::cout << "reference access" << std::endl;
            return m_var;
        }
        
        C* operator->() {
            std::cout << "pointer access" << std::endl;
            return &m_var;
        }
        
        Modificator& operator=(const C& other)
        {
            std::cout << "assignment access" << std::endl;
            m_var = other;
            return *this;
        }
        
        private:
        StatVar<S, C>& m_stat_var;
        C m_var;
    };
    
    operator C const&() const {
        std::shared_lock lock(m_mutex);
        return m_var;
    }
    
    C const* operator->() const {
        std::shared_lock lock(m_mutex);
        return &m_var;
    }
    
    C const& operator*() const {
        std::shared_lock lock(m_mutex);
        return m_var;
    }
    
    template <typename K>
    auto const& operator[](const K& key) const {
        std::shared_lock lock(m_mutex);
        return m_var[key];
    }
    
    Modificator modyfy() {
        std::unique_lock lock(m_mutex);
        return Modificator(*this);
    }
    
    private:
    C m_var;
    friend class Modificator;
    std::shared_ptr<S> m_storage;
    mutable std::shared_mutex m_mutex;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    
    std::shared_ptr<TestStorage> storage{new TestStorage()};
    
    StatVar<TestStorage, int> i(storage, 0);
    i.modyfy() = 10;
    std::cout << "new i: " << i << std::endl;
    std::cout << "end" << std::endl;
    
    StatVar<TestStorage, std::string> s(storage, "test");
    s.modyfy()->push_back('1');
    s.modyfy()[s->size() - 1] = '0';
    std::cout << "new size: " << s->size() << std::endl << "new data: " << static_cast<const std::string&>(s) << std::endl;
    
    StatVar<TestStorage, std::vector<std::string>> v(storage, {"test1"s, "test2"s, "test3"s});
    v.modyfy()->push_back("test");
    v.modyfy()[v->size() - 1] = "test4";
    std::cout << "new size: " << v->size() << std::endl << "new data: " << static_cast<const std::string&>(v[v->size() - 1]) << std::endl;

/*    
    StatVar<TestStorage, std::map<std::string, int>> m(storage, {std::pair<std::string, int>{"test1"s, 1}, std::pair<std::string, int>{"test2"s, 2}, std::pair<std::string, int>{"test3"s, 3}});
    m.modyfy()->insert({"test4"s, 0});
    m.modyfy()["test4"s] = 4;
    std::cout << "new size: " << m->size() << std::endl << "new data: " << static_cast<const int&>(m->at("test4"s)) << std::endl;
    
compiller error:

main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘StatVar<S, C>::StatVar(const std::shared_ptr<_Tp>&, std::initializer_list<U>, Args&& ...) [with U = std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>; Args = {}; S = TestStorage; C = std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>]’:
main.cpp:127:191:   required from here
main.cpp:23:107: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map, int>::map()’
   23 |     explicit StatVar(std::shared_ptr<S> const& storage, std::initializer_list<U> ilist, Args&&... args) : m_var{ilist, std::forward<Args>(args)...}, m_storage{storage} {}
      |                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*/

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give an example, what exactly happens if you try this: _"I could not implement access to the maps by index."_ [mcve] as required here please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I basically do not know how to do this, since the type of the map key is unknown

Comment: `auto& operator[](std::size_t i)` -> `template <typename K> auto& operator[](const K& key)`?

Comment: @Jarod42 I updated the code, it works with a vector, but not with a map

Comment: [`std::map` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) takes `initializer_list<std::pair<const Key, value>>` Notice the `const`. That fixes it [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/a1dnYr3Yn)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks, it works now, but why isn't the type automatically inferred from {{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}}?

Comment: `{..}` has no type, and is limited in deduction to initializer_list or C-array.

Comment: And why is it `std::map <std::string, int> m{{"test1", 1}, {"test2", 2}, {"test3", 3}};` works?